# Getting Started with TensorFlow documentation

Tags: tensorflow

I am not sure if this is the right place to raise this. I was following https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started and came across the following sample code:

```
W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)

b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = W * x + b


In the section on loss function it has the following:

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

Why is value of `y [0,-1,-2,-3]`? Based on

```
linear_model = W * x + b,
```

y would be 0.3x - 0.3. So for x of [1,2,3,4], y should be [0,0.3,0.6,0.9].
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing something. The goal of this exercise is to show that you first build up a graph (W*x+b=y), and then supply the variables for the placeholders. 
To do this you supply x and y, and see what the difference is between wat you expected (the y variable) and what you got (the linear_model variable).

You are confusing the result of the equation with what the tutorial wanted to get out of this equation. If you go on in the tutorial they will probably learn you how you can train your weights to get the solution you expect.

Good luck!

Comment: and also meertens for the clarifications

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet, 'x' is the input and 'y' serves the purpose of label as you seem to already understand.

'W' and 'b' are variables that the program should 'learn' such that when x=[1,2,3,4], y ends up as [0,-1,-2,-3].

The values of 'W' and 'b' you see are the initial values.
Not included in this code is the update step where you will update the weights after computing the gradient based on a loss function. And after a few iterations, you should get your 'W' and 'b' such that when x=[1,2,3,4], you will get y=[0,-1,-2,-3]